# Starting project with NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm having problem to start a project with NextJS. I just start a project with `npx create-next-app <projectName>` and without changing any file I run `yarn dev` on terminal. The following error appears: `SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared`. I tried to search online but I couldn't anything on this.

PS: Something that I tried: This error occurs on Chrome but not on Internet Explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has nothing to do with Next.js and it was caused by one of your Chrome extensions (probably by Grammarly).

[Tableau says](http://web.archive.org/web/20210312003543/https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/Uncaught-Syntaxerror-Identifier-originalprompt-Has-Already-Been-Declared) the error is caused by the Grammarly extension that is interfering with the loading of the dashboard. There's [a user mentioning it](https://github.com/honeypotio/staticpages/issues/779#issuecomment-772522955) on the Honeypot GitHub repo that this is due to a bug in the Grammarly browser extension.

On the anvil.works forum [a user mentioned](https://anvil.works/forum/t/internal-error-in-official-custom-user-authentication/7429/4) that the Chrome Widget "Selenium" triggered the error and after they deleted it, all their apps worked fine again. There is [another post](https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/5qxG12KTC-0?pli=1) in the Selenium users Google group where a user says that they're using the Selenium IDE and received the same `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared"`.

If you've got any of these extensions, try to disable them.

Comment: Thank you man! IThe problem really was on google extension Katalon. After I removed everything works just fine!!